# Restricting access to URLs in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to restrict access to certain URLs in Struts 2?  I already have it so you can't access jsp's directly, but you can access them indirectly.  For example if I have a jsp "blah.jsp" I can access it by typing "/blah" and if I don't have an Action called Blah.java, it will automatically go to the result, blah.jsp.  Most of the time this is what I want, but there will be some jsps that I don't want to be access this way, like "blah-success.jsp".  Is there a way to say that, I can't navigate to any url's that look like "/-success"?

Edit:
I almost have it working...

```
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>

<package name="my-secure-url" extends="my-secure" namespace="/secure**">
    <action name="*"> 
        <interceptor-ref name="secureStack"/>
        <result>{1}</result>
    </action> 
</package>
```

This works if I try to visit "/secure/anything/anything/etc" and I'm not logged in, I get directed to the login page.  However if I just logged in and I'm at "http://localhost:8080/Struts2NewChapter8/secure/admin-portfolio" and I click a link to "http://localhost:8080/Struts2NewChapter8/secure/update/update-account-form" I get errors that look like this:

```
    WARNING: Error setting expression '0' with value '/secure/update'
    ognl.InappropriateExpressionException: Inappropriate OGNL expression: 0
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValueBody(SimpleNode.java:312)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:198)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:149)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:155)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:92)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But of course.  Struts matches [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) in the order they appear in your config file, so the last one that matches a request will be the one used (i.e. less specific matches must be before more specific matches).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
 <action name="*">
   <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}.ftl</result>
 </action>  

 <action name="*-success">
   <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/access-denied.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

The above will keep your current behaviour and cause any file with a **-success** suffix in the name to end up at access-denied.jsp.

**Edit:** You'll need to enable this property to have slashes in your action names:

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
```

To make it conditional, I would use an interceptor stack that checked if a user was logged in before forwarding to the .jsp:

```
 <action name="secure/*">
   <interceptor-ref name="authenticationStack"/>  
   <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

In your authenticationStack you would need an Interceptor that determines if a user is logged in.  If not you would forward them to an access-denied.jsp type page from within the interceptor.  The [Struts docs on Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html) should help you out.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks!  I'm trying to do something a little bit similar now.  Now the url I want to catch is anything in the "/secure/" area.  So my action name is "*/secure/*" but this isn't working.  Furthermore, is there a way to make it conditional?  I only want to catch this if a user is not logged in.

Comment: I tried your updates but they didn't work.  I had the interceptor already in place, it's the struts.xml part that isn't working.  The interceptor never gets called.  I included the constant, and the action part.

Comment: Since you're now logged in and not being forwarded by the interceptor, my guess is that struts doesn't know how to handle the wildcard '/secure**' namespace definition.